# Fastest Way To std::vector<Derived> to std::vector<Base>

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, vector, stl

Here is the test code:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};

void Test(const std::vector<A>& a)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::vector<B> b;
    Test(a);
    Test(b);//Compiler Error
    return 0;
}
```

Since `std::vector<A>` and `std::vector<B>` is different type, we can't make conversion from one to another.

An optional way can be:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};

void Test(const std::vector<A>& a)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::vector<B> b;
    Test(a);
    Test(std::vector<A>(b.begin(), b.end()));
    return 0;
}
```

It acts, but it takes extra copying from `B` to `A`. If `A` or `B` is a large object, it can be very slow. A better choice is:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};

void Test(const std::vector<A>& a)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::vector<B> b;
    Test(a);
    Test(std::vector<A>(std::make_move_iterator(b.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(b.end())));
    return 0;
}
```

Since it just move the iter instead of the whole `B` class, it take a better performance. But there are some extra cost - If `b` is a very large vector with huge number of items, iteration also can slow down my code.

So I wonder if there is a way to directly convert `std::vector<B>` to `std::vector<A>` without any extra cost?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just move the iter". The last example move-constructs instances of `A` from instances of `B`, leaving contents of `b` in an indeterminate state in the process (which may or may not be a problem). Anyway, no, there's no magical cost-free way to construct a `vector<A>` from a `vector<B>`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make the vector a template parameter of the Test function. The calling code will remain the same, there is no copying required.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }   
};
class B : public A{
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }   
};

template <typename ContainerA>
void Test(const ContainerA& aas)
{
    for(const A& a:aas) {
        a.print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    a.push_back(A());
    std::vector<B> b;
    b.push_back(B());
    Test(a);
    Test(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bonus point for a useful concept constraining `ContainerA` from `Test`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's useful for you but the best I can think is pass `std::vector<Derived>` to the function and iterate the element as `Base` elements.

Something like

```
template <typename D>
void Test (std::vector<D> const & v)
 {
   for ( A const & elem : v )
    {
      // use elem
    }
 }
```

Using SFINAE you can enable `Test()` only for vectors of `Base` or derived from `Base` elements as follows

```
template <typename D>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, D>::value>::type
     Test (std::vector<D> const & v)
 {
   for ( A const & elem : v )
    {
      // use elem
    }
 }
```

So you have

```
int main ()
 {
   std::vector<A>   a;
   std::vector<B>   b;
   std::vector<int> c;

   Test(a);    // compile
   Test(b);    // compile
   // Test(c); // compiler error
 }
```

Comment: This is a way acted but sometimes `Test` is a 3rd-party function which you should not change it